# How to obtain default language files in languages other than English

Tags: laravel

When you want to work with Localization, the Laravel documentation says that we must execute the Artisan lang:publish command to publish the language files and then we can modify them as we wish. These files are published in English by default.

The default language files are auth, pagination, passwords and validations.

The question is how can I obtain these files in languages other than English, such as Spanish. Do I need to create and translate them manually or can they be obtained somehow?

I read the official Laravel documentation about Localization but nothing is said about this topic.

Comment: yes, you need to create their equivalent in whatever language you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a package that has all the translations you could ever need.

[Laravel Lang](https://laravel-lang.com/introduction.html#introduction)

**Support Projects﻿:**

-Laravel Framework

-Laravel Jetstream

-Laravel Fortify

-Laravel Breeze

-Laravel Cashier

-Laravel Nova

-Laravel Nova Dusk Suite

-Laravel Nova Log Viewer

-Laravel Spark (Stripe, Paddle, Aurelius, Aurelius Mollie)

-Laravel UI

-and other

I hope it can be of use to someone else.